# Firebase App Check iOS - Cannot find type 'AppCheckProviderFactory' in scope

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, swift-package-manager, firebase-app-check

- Xcode version: 12.5.1
- Firebase SDK version: 8.5.0
- Installation method: Swift Package Manager
- Firebase Component: App Check

I'm getting error using the sample code in app delegate (Step 3 here: [Setup Firebase App Check on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider?authuser=0)):

> "Cannot find type 'AppCheckProviderFactory' in scope"

First, I tried importing FirebaseAppCheck, but that wasn't recognized. I can import Firebase fine (and I'm using that in my app already), but that doesn't seem get me hooked into App Check. When I look in the downloaded Firebase package, I see FirebaseAppCheck.

I reset my package cache and cleaned the build folder, neither of which resolved the issue. Is App Check intended to work with SPM, or should I be importing the framework manually? Or, (probably more likely), am I missing something obvious here?

Following code returns two errors: Cannot find type 'AppCheckProviderFactory' in scope & Cannot find type 'AppCheckProvider' in scope.

```
import Firebase

class SimpleAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
  func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
    return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
  }
}
```

If anyone can point in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing App Check Library, ex: `import FirebaseAppCheck`. Tested via SwiftPM.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAppCheck

final class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let providerFactory = SweetAppCheckProviderFactory()
    let providerFactory = AppCheckDebugProviderFactory() // for dev
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct SweetApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class SweetAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
    func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
        return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
    }
}
```